# Array class as new module in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

I need to add some prototype to `Array` class,in native javascript I can do following

```
 var myArray = Array;
 myArray.prototype.myMethod = function(){}
 var testArray = new myArray();
 testArray.contains();
```

but now I need to do this by node js module and **exports** `myArray` as class so can make some object from it,how can I do this?

Comment: Why do you want to export `myArray` at all when it *is* just the globally available `Array`?

Comment: add some prototype to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add to the Array prototype directly from within a module, it'll be accessible to the Array in the main scope

To see this, put the following line in `foo.js`:

```
Array.prototype.foo = "bar";
```

Then fire up the repl and run

```
$ node
> Array.prototype.foo
undefined // <-- Array normally doesn't have foo
> require('./foo')
{}
> Array.prototype.foo
'bar' // <-- note how it's defined now
> [].foo
'bar' // <-- as expected
```

You can do the same thing with other basic objects like `Number`